# REST stages should be configured to use SSL certificates for backend authentication

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, nestjs, aws-serverless

I'm trying to pass a security compliance check under AWS Security Hub - [APIGateway.2] API Gateway REST API stages should be configured to use SSL certificates for backend authentication.

What have I done?

1. created a Client Certificate from AWS API Gateway
2. selected an API and attached generated Client Certificate to a stage
3. copied generated Client Certificate's key into *secrets/apig-cert.pem* of backend
4. updated index service as below

```
const nestApplicationOptions: NestApplicationOptions = {
    httpsOptions: {
        ca: [fs.readFileSync('secrets/apig-cert.pem')],
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
    },
};
const expressApp = express();
const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(expressApp);
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(
    AppModule,
    adapter,
    nestApplicationOptions,
);
...
await app.init();
await awsServerlessExpress.createServer(expressApp);
```

Expected behaviour:

- Under Security Hub, corresponding compliance status check should pass
- If client certificate is detached from API stage under API Gateway, lambda service should throw invalid certificate error

Current behaviour:

- Combining step 1 and 2 together resolved the compliance status check
- API works in all cases, even if the certificate is detached from the API stage under the API Gateway

I'm not sure what is missing here. Something I believe is fishy with how I'm using `NestFactory.create` or `awsServerlessExpress.createServer`.

Extra info:

- API mapping is done to the same stage from API Gateway > Custom domain names

Reference links-

- [fsbp-apigateway-2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/securityhub-standards-fsbp-controls.html#fsbp-apigateway-2)
- [Getting started with client side SSL authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

@kartoon if you pay attention to the documentation it says

`Before configuring a backend HTTPS server to verify the client SSL certificate of API Gateway, you must have obtained the PEM-encoded private key and a server-side certificate that is provided by a trusted certificate authority.`

Your server side code should have the private key configured with a cert that if will present to API gateway.
If you look at the sample express code provided in the AWS documentation, below are the two lines I am talking about.

```
key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'), 
cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),
```

Your code in that case should look like

```
const nestApplicationOptions: NestApplicationOptions = {
    httpsOptions: {
        ca: [fs.readFileSync('CA-SIGNER-CERT.pem')],
        cert: [fs.readFileSync('PUBLIC-CERT.pem')],
        key: [fs.readFileSync('PRIVATE-KEY.key')],
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
    },
};
```

Comment: Since this is done over lambda, how would we get `key` and `cert` as lambda already internally works with https without any external certification setting?

Comment: For the SSL handshake to happen your server needs to present a server cert and also have a private key that would be used to decrypt the traffic encrypted by public key. the public key is part of server's cert. Lambda will not provide any of these. you can use openssl to create a private key and server certificate req. The server cert req will need to be signed by a trusted CA. Both the private key and server cert can be held in Secrets Manager and loaded outside the handler in Lambda. Example https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/